# Method to get JList from its ListSelectionModel

Tags: java, swing, jlist

Is there a method in Java to get the `JList` if we know the `ListSelectionModel`? The code below is from a my `ListSelectionListener`:

```
    ListSelectionModel lsm=(ListSelectionModel)event.getSource();

    JList jl=lsm.someMethodIdLiketoKnow();
```

The `ListSelectionListener` is added onto this `ListSelectionModel`:

```
    myjlist.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(myListSelectionListener);
```

The other question is why wouldn't I just add the listener onto the `JList` directly and forget about the `ListSelectionModel` altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be possible to obtain "the" `JList` from a given `ListSelectionModel`, because there may be *multiple* lists that have the *same* `ListSelectionModel`:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SharedListSelectionModel
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        DefaultListModel modelA = new DefaultListModel();
        JList listA = new JList(modelA);
        DefaultListModel modelB = new DefaultListModel();
        JList listB = new JList(modelB);
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            modelA.addElement("A"+i);
            modelB.addElement("B"+i);
        }

        ListSelectionModel selectionModel = new DefaultListSelectionModel();
        listA.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
        listB.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);

        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
        p.add(new JScrollPane(listA));
        p.add(new JScrollPane(listB));
        f.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        f.setSize(300,300);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The *selection model* is a model on its own (roughly, in the meaning of the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)). But as icza pointed out in his answer: You can also add the selection listener to the `JList`.

Another solution is that you manually associate the listener and the list. Often, this can be done rather locally, in an anonymous inner class:

```
// Declare list as "final" (or make it a field of the enclosing class)
final JList list = ...;
list.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
    {
        // Can access the list here:
        Object object = list.getSelectedValue();
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `ListSelectionListener`s both to the `JList` itself and to its `ListSelectionModel`.

The event source will be the object you add the listener to, so if you add it to `JList`, `event.getSource()` will return the `JList`. If you add the listener to the `ListSelectionModel`, `event.getSource()` will return the `ListSelectionModel`.

If you add your listener to the `JList` itself, the `JList` implementation handles the "listening" of the underlying model and will translate/create new events which will be dispatched to the listener you register, and the source will be set properly to the `JList`.

If you still want to add the listener to the model, you can't "extract" the `JList` out of the event because it will only store the `ListSelectionModel` as the source and it does not know about the `JList`. You have to manage the reference yourself. In this example it is simply availabe because `final` local variables can be accessed from anonymous classes:

```
final JList<String> list = new JList<>(new String[]{"One", "Two"});
list.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        // JList cannot be "extracted from the event
        // But we know its reference, e.g.
        System.out.println("JList is:" + list);
    }
});
```